# What is the correct Address of a C++ function or function pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, function-pointers

```cpp
typedef int (*fooPtr)(int);

int foo(int a) {
    return a + 1;
}


int main(){

    void* funcPtr1 = reinterpret_cast<void*>(foo);
    void* funcPtr2 = foo;
    void* funcPtr3 = &foo;
    fooPtr funcPtr4 = foo;


}
```

in Visual Studio's Watch window I get the same address for all funcPtr's (1-4) but when I type in the function name itself `foo`; I get a different address. What is the actual address of the function `foo`.
Meaning, the actual code that the assembler will eventually run. and what is the alternate address then?

[image: watch window]

Comment: Function pointers are not interoperable with data pointers like `void*`.

Comment: @Eljay They are on Windows, compiler extension

Comment: This must have something to do with the inner working of MS-Windows C++ ABI. For a well-formed C++ program it is completely irrelevant. The actual memory address of one of its functions is not something that a C++ program will ever care about. Correct usage of function pointers results in the compiler taking care of all of these details for you.

Comment: You should tag with the name of your compiler/implementation, since this is an implementation detail, not a generic language issue

Comment: @NateEldredge this is visual studio so I thought it would be implied that this is msvc.

Comment: @MrBrN197: Yes.  I'm suggesting that you also include this information as a **tag**.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this with Visual Studio 2017 and I found out that the actual function is located at the address that the debugger displays for "foo". The code at the four "funcPtr" addresses just contains a `jmp` instruction to the actual address of the function. However, this only applies to debug builds. With release builds, the addresses are identical.

Comment: @Eljay C++ doesn't _require_ it, but POSIX does require function pointers to round-trip conversion to `void*`, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html

Comment: @AndreasWenzel That's interesting. I wonder if it is so you can put breakpoints on different function pointers.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel this is interesting. in fact I just noticed that it's a pointer to a list of `jmp` instructions. from the address every 5 bytes after, starts with `e9` the opcode for a jump. like you said this must be something to do with debugging on msvc but I'm interested to find out how you evaluated the address without using debug build?

Comment: @MrBrN197: I just used the "Disassembly" window of the debugger and entered the name of the pointers (or function) into it. However, in the code you posted, the pointer variables will be optimized away in release builds, because they have no observable effects. Therefore, I had to add a `printf( "%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n", funcPtr1, funcPtr2, funcPtr3, funcPtr4 );` to prevent the pointer variables from being optimized away.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel oh.. cool. I thought the function itself also wouldn't show up for some reason but it does. thanks Andreas.